# The CK editor instance is already attached to the provided element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am just playing with CK Editor at the moment, trying to get my head around saving the data to a database. However this error comes up in the console, want to make sure I am not doing anything wrong.

I am using the following HTML as part of a dynamic bootstrap tab system, don't think that is interfering.

"Uncaught The editor instance "testEditor" is already attached to the provided element."

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
  CKEDITOR.inline("testEditor");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="testEditor" name="testEditor" class="tab-pane fade" contenteditable="true">
        <h3 id="test1">
          Test
        </h3>
        <p style="font-size: 15px;" id="test2">
          This is a test. Line 1<br>
          Line 2<br>
          Line 3
        </p>
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold;" id="test3">
          Test
        </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;` before `$(document).ready`.